# How to search and replace an object in a multidimensional array in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm a total beginner at programming and I have an assignment in class to create a bingo card using a twodimensional array of 5x5 and fill it with random numbers between 1-25.
I have done this BUT now I need to search the array for doubles and if there are any, switch them out. Or check while filling the array.
I also need to check if the users chosen numbers make a bingo row.

I have tried figuring this out for days but I can't make it work and the solutions I have found are too complicated for me to understand and use.
I have to turn it in today and my teacher is not responding because it's sunday :(

Please help!

```
for (int i = 0; i < bingo.GetLength(0); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < bingo.GetLength(1); j++) {
    random  = rnd.Next(1, 25);
    bingo[i,j] = random;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Doubles as in duplicates?

Comment: @CruleD Yes exactly, the numbers on the bingo card should only appear once.

Comment: Hint: Instead of creating a two dimensional array, create a single dimension array, sort it randomly, and then use nested loops to convert it to a two dimensional array.

Comment: You can create a list (for example) before your loop, then while looping you check if List contains your number, and do stuff based on that and also add new ones to it. For bingo, you can make a counter and while you loop it if it does match, increment by one then if it's the same as row length upon end, that's a bingo.

Comment: " I also need to check if the users chosen numbers make a bingo row." You need to keep a list of the indexes of chosen numbers, and every time a user choose that number, update the list and then check if you have 5 in a row (or column, or diagonal, I guess)

Comment: I agree that selecting 5x5 numbers from 1-25 with no duplicates is actually just _creating a random ordering_ of the all the numbers from 1-25.  (because 5x5 = 25).  As you gain experience, you'll eventually be able to formulate your wording of the problem in a way that more closely matches the algorithm required.

Answer (score 0):

Code in first answer was a bit clumsy, so I removed it. This one's better and quite an easy algorithm, just scramble your range of numbers an assign them.

```
var l1 = 5;
var l2 = 5;
int [,] bingo = new int[l1, l2];        

var rnd = new Random();
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,l1 * l2).OrderBy(i => rnd.NextDouble()).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < l2; j++) {
        bingo[i,j] = numbers[(i * l1) + j];
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}, {1}] = {2}", i, j, bingo[i,j]);
    }
}
```